# chrome extension popup same tab still not working

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I used the code I found here.
But it´s still not working out to open my link out of the popup.html in the currently active tab.

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>

<html>








    <style>
body {
  min-width: 156px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
div {
    margin:1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
</style>


    <head>

        <title>I-Serv Switcher</title>

        <script src="js.js"></script>

    </head>
  <body>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><div style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:blue; float:left;">Click.</div></a>



  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see there is a little blue div. when i add target="_blank", then google opens in a new tab. But adding the following .js should take the link out of the clicked div with href and open it in the active tab.

js.js

```
var hrefs = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

function openLink() {
    var href = this.href;
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: href});
    });
}

for (var i=0,a; a=hrefs[i]; ++i) {
    hrefs[i].addEventListener('click', openLink);
}
```

the permission "tabs" is given in the manifest.json

What am i doing wrong ? 
Did  I forget something ?

Comment: By the way, you don't need `tabs` permission for this. It is only needed to read data about existing tabs (like the URL or the title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code executes at the moment the `<script>` tag is read.

The rest of the DOM is not constructed yet; `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` is, therefore, empty.

To fix this, you need to wrap your code in a `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var hrefs = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

  /* ... */
});
```

---

Note that you can easily debug your popup by right-clicking your extension's button and selecting "Inspect popup"

Comment: Thank you, this works fine.

But the popup is not closing anymore.

Do I have to add something ?